# Installation failed to create the core tables | Installing Revive Adserver 5.2.0

Tags: mysqli

I am installing revive ad server on Ubuntu 20.4 which is having MySQL Version 8.0.23. The Log I got from file /var/debug.log is

```
[Last executed query: CREATE TABLE `bv_banners` (`bannerid` MEDIUMINT(9) AUTO_INCREMENT   NOT NULL, `campaignid` MEDIUMINT(9) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, `contenttype` ENUM('gif','jpeg','png','html','swf','dcr','rpm','mov','txt') DEFAULT 'gif' NOT NULL, `pluginversion` MEDIUMINT(9) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, `storagetype` ENUM('sql','web','url','html','network','txt') DEFAULT 'sql' NOT NULL, `filename` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, `imageurl` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, `htmltemplate` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL, `htmlcache` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL, `width` SMALLINT(6) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, `height` SMALLINT(6) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, `weight` TINYINT(4) DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL, `seq` TINYINT(4) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, `target` VARCHAR(16) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, `url` TEXT NOT NULL, `alt` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, `statustext` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, `bannertext` TEXT NOT NULL, `description` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, `adserver` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, `block` INT(11) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, `capping` INT(11) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, `session_capping` INT(11) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, `compiledlimitation` TEXT NOT NULL, `acl_plugins` TEXT DEFAULT NULL, `append` TEXT NOT NULL, `bannertype` TINYINT(4) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, `alt_filename` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, `alt_imageurl` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, `alt_contenttype` ENUM('gif','jpeg','png') DEFAULT 'gif' NOT NULL, `comments` TEXT DEFAULT NULL, `updated` DATETIME NOT NULL, `acls_updated` DATETIME DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL, `keyword` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, `transparent` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, `parameters` TEXT DEFAULT NULL, `status` INT(11) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, `ext_bannertype` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, `prepend` TEXT NOT NULL, `iframe_friendly` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (bannerid)) ENGINE = INNODB]

[Native message: Invalid default value for 'acls_updated']
```

I got to know adserver is not officially supporting mysql version 8. But some people are able to run fine. I want to know how.
Here is the refrence I got
https://github.com/revive-adserver/revive-adserver/issues/1048

I want to run this.[image]
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `sql_mode='40''` to `sql_mode=''`

in 5 files;

1. `lib/OA/DB.php`
2. `lib/OA/DaL/Delivery/mysql.php`
3. `lib/OA/Dal/Delivery/mysqli.php`
4. `lib/OA/Upgrade/DB_Upgrade.php`
5. `lib/OA/Upgrade/Upgrade.php`

and use table type INNODB

This trick works for me. I am  calling this as a trick because it is not officially supported.
I got solution from github.
Here is the refrence
https://github.com/revive-adserver/revive-adserver/issues/1048